# Xcode, iOs Development: Log every Controllername

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I currently work into a big project that consists of lots of classes. Can you imagine a way to get a log message with the name of the controller everytime a controller is loaded?
The background is following: When I have to fix a bug, I spend quite much time with searching for the corresponding source code. It would help me a lot if I click through the app in the simulator and see which class I am currently in.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this easily, you may :

1- create a UIViewControllerEnhanced view controller that inherits from UIViewController
2- Override its `viewDidLoad` method (or any init method depending on what you want) like this :

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad for class %@", self.className);
}
```

3- in your project, replace in all your view controller the possible UIViewController inheritance by UIViewControllerEnhanced class.

That's it :-)

Comment: Thanks! However, we have a few hundred classes. Is there no way to do this without editing every existing file?

Comment: @user688262 : I don't see a simplier way. But this editing is quite simple. just search all ": UIViewController" in your files (you should only get .h files) and replace the with ": UIViewControllerEnhanced". That may be easy.

Answer (score 3):

In big project you probably don't want to change all UIViewControllers to subclass with overridden -viewDidLoad method. You can change implementation of -viewDidLoad at the runtime by using method swizzling. By this way you can add name logging to -viewDidLoad with saving original implementation. Check out this: http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-01-29-method-replacement-for-fun-and-profit.html

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIViewController (LoadLogging)

void MethodSwizzle(Class c, SEL origSEL, SEL overrideSEL);

- (void)override_viewDidLoad {

    [self override_viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"%@ loaded", self);
}

+ (void)load
{
    MethodSwizzle(self, @selector(viewDidLoad), @selector(override_viewDidLoad));
}


void MethodSwizzle(Class c, SEL origSEL, SEL overrideSEL)
{
    Method origMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(c, origSEL);
    Method overrideMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(c, overrideSEL);
    if(class_addMethod(c, origSEL, method_getImplementation(overrideMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(overrideMethod)))
    {
        class_replaceMethod(c, overrideSEL, method_getImplementation(origMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(origMethod));
    }
    else
    {
        method_exchangeImplementations(origMethod, overrideMethod);
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one in all classes:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Working class is %@",self);

}
```